# How can I find all files open within a given directory?

Tags: linux, find, lsof

I know I can use `lsof` to list open files, and I know I can use `find` to find files by inode within a given directory.

But how can I effectively combine these two programs to list all open files which are open within a given directory? Or is there a better way to answer this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. Just pipe the output of the [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) command into [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for further processing like this:

```
sudo lsof | grep /path/of/directory/you/care/about
```

Answer (score 29):

`lsof` has switches for doing this:

- `lsof +d '/path/to/directory'` (will list open files in the folder)
- `lsof +D '/path/to/directory'` (will list open files recursively)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you just care about the current working directory, you can do `lsof +d .`